# Discord.py v2 Buttons

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot for blackjack which has 4 buttons: hit, stand, double-down and split.

When the user runs the command `/blackjack` I don't want to display all the buttons right away.
I only want to show hit stand double down, this means no split,

so how do I edit this line of code:

```
await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=Buttons())
```

to make me able to exclude the button split for now?

Comment: can you include your Buttons() view code as well?

Comment: Don't add the button to the view yet, and update the view later on.